# Luxon how to set date to last monday of a month?

Tags: javascript, luxon

I'm trying to define holidays in Luxon, such as memorial day which is the last Monday of May. How can I generate a luxon date object with this:

```
DateTime.now().set({ month: 5, weekday: 1 })
```

Is there a way to specify last week in Luxon without knowing the exact date?

Comment: You probably don't want this suggestion, but get the first day of the next month, then `DateTime.local(2023, 6, 1).weekday` to get the day of the week ( https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimeweekday ) and subtract the number days needed to arrive at Monday ( https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimeminus , since you know that every week only has 7 days).

Comment: `let temp = DateTime.now().set({ month: 5 }).endOf('month').startOf('week');` Since the start of the week is Monday in Luxon, I would think this would always return the last Monday. But I don't know Luxon past reading [the documentation](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimestartof).

Comment: @HereticMonkey it's perfect.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, that would work. I was hoping to be able to do it directly from passing units into set() as I'm defining the rules in a mongoDB object but after reading more it does seem that's not possible.

Comment: You could get it by setting the units if you knew what year it was and in which week of that year Memorial Day occurs. Set the `weekNumber` property to that week number, with the properties you've already set, and I think you'd be good to go. The challenge is knowing which week number Memorial Day falls in, without knowing when Memorial Day is :).

Comment: Yup, thats the issue with weekNumber is that weekNumber will change overtime :(

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime.now().set({ month: 5 }).endOf('month').startOf('week');
```

From my understanding, Luxon's weeks always start on Monday, so asking for the [start of](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimestartof) the week after getting the [end of](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimeendof) the month of May should get you the last Monday of May (of the current year if your starting point is `DateTime.now()`).

Answer (score 1):

You can, of course also do it without Luxon by using some basic `Date` functionality:

```js
function getLastMondayOfMay(y){
 const dd=new Date(y,4,31), wd=dd.getDay(); // set date to last day of May and get weekday
 dd.setDate(31-(wd+7-1)%7); // find the closest Monday before that
 return dd;
}

const options = {weekday: "long",year: "numeric",month: "long",
                day: "numeric"};

[2018,2019,2020,2021,2022,2023,2024,2025].forEach(y=>
  console.log(getLastMondayOfMay(y).toLocaleString('en-EN',options)))
```